# Xamarin forms - set switch text color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can I set the color of the text in an android renderer? I have the following renderer:

```
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.TextOn = "Yes";
            Control.TextOff = "No";

            Android.Graphics.Color colorOn = Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(239, 201, 6);
            Android.Graphics.Color colorOff = Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray;
            Android.Graphics.Color colorDisabled = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
            Android.Graphics.Color textColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;

            Control.SetTextColor (ColorStateList.ValueOf  (textColor));
            Control.SetTextColor (textColor);

            StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
            drawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked }, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
            drawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled }, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
            drawable.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(colorOff));

            Control.ThumbDrawable = drawable;

        }
    }
}
```

I am able to change the color of the switch, but I can't figure out how to change the color of the YES/NO text. SetTextColor doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an xml file under the Resources\values directory in your droid project.
doesn't matter the name but it needs to end in .xml and contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your renderer call Control.SetSwitchTextAppearance. Pass in the Context and the ResId of the resource you created. You can get the Id from the generated file under Resources titled Resource.designer.cs. Alternately you can call the Const that generated as follows.

```
Control.SetSwitchTextAppearance (Control.Context, Resource.Style.CodeFont);
```

Hope it helps. If you cant get it let me know Ill upload a sample app.

Comment: Hi could you upload a sample app with custom renders for both iOS and Droid.