# Xamarin forms change SwichCell Text Color

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is it possible to change the text color of xamarins **SwichCell** ?

At the moment the text in my SwichCell is colored gray, and I want to change it to black.

My xaml looks like this:

```
..

<TableView Intent="Data" >
    <TableRoot>;
        <TableSection>
            <SwitchCell Text="Allow Push Notifications"/>
        </TableSection>
        <TableSection>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Log Out" Clicked="LogOutButtonClick" Margin="-20,-20,-20,-20"/>
            </ViewCell.View>
         </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
        <TableSection>
            <TextCell Text="Android Version 1.2.1" TextColor="Black"/>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

The only thing regarding this I found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24844/text-aligment-and-color-in-switchcell) but the example is only for IOS and the other provided solutions uses TextCell and Swich combination, which does not fit my scenario (I think)

Someone has linked a stackoverflow answer regarding **Swich** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214210/xamarin-forms-set-switch-text-color). But it does not work for my situacion since I'm using **SwichCell** and it does not have the properties that are listed in that answer(also it only has an android version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin forms - set switch text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214210/xamarin-forms-set-switch-text-color)

Comment: I think your options would be to use a Viewcell with either a StackPanel in Horizontal orientation or a Grid Layout with a Label and a Switch, or a custom renderer which modifies the SwitchCell to implement your own custom text color.

Answer (score 0):

If the SwitchCell doesn't expose a *BackgroundColor* Property, you can just wrap the Switch Control in its own ViewCell.

Can't Confirm the syntax, but something like this:

```
 <ViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
       <Switch BackgroundColor="Black"/>
     </StackLayout>
 </ViewCell>
```